# Как изменить поле в list_display? | django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model

Имеется поле, которое необходимо сделать ссылкой на другую модель, которая будет автоматически открываться при нажатии на это поле в `list_display`.

[image: Django-admin]

Как сделать так, чтобы открывалась другая модель при нажатии на поле, как на примере **ЕГО МОДЕЛЬ**? В этом случае, по идее открыватся совсем другая модель, не относящаяся к этим. То есть, открывается модель **условного реферала**.

Если что-то не так пояснил, то в комментариях постараюсь прояснить картину :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Довольно банальный, пришлось немного заглянуть в документацию.

```
...
from django.utils.html import format_html
...


class Model(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', ..., 'to_agent', ...)

    def to_agent(obj):
        return format_html(
            '<a href="/custom_link/{id}">{name}</a>',
            id=123,
            name='ЕГО МОДЕЛЬ'
        )
```